# D3 Multi Line Graph with Dots

Tags: charts, d3.js, line

I am new to D3.js. I love it but I am having real trouble figuring out the best approach to structuring data.

I would ideally like to create a simple multiline graph that has over points over the selected  points. Firstly I have the multiple lines created but trying to add the points has stumped me, and I think it has to do with the structure of my data.

[Here is my working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hTK6B/14/). I'm not sure if I should be trying to use d3.nest to re-arrange the data

I have a json object that I am retrieving from a google form which is all nice and smooth. This is what it looks like:

```
var data = [{
"description": "Global warming is a serious and pressing problem. We should begin taking steps now even if this involves significant costs",
"year2013": 40,
"year2012": 36,
"year2011": 41,
"year2010": 46,
"year2009": 48,
"year2008": 60,
"year2006": 68,
}, {
"description": "The problem of global warming should be addressed, but its effects will be gradual, so we can deal with the problem gradually by taking steps that are low in cost",
"year2013": 44,
"year2012": 45,
"year2011": 40,
"year2010": 40,
"year2009": 39,
"year2008": 32,
"year2006": 24,
}, {
"description": "Until we are sure that global warming is really a problem, we should not take any steps that would have economic costs",
"year2013": 16,
"year2012": 18,
"year2011": 19,
"year2010": 13,
"year2009": 13,
"year2008": 8,
"year2006": 7,

}, {
"description": "Don't know / refused",
"year2013": 1,
"year2012": 1,
"year2011": 1,
"year2010": 1,
"year2009": 1,
"year2008": 0,
"year2006": 1,

}]
```

Any help would be appreciated, I have been at it for days.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

First - I would flatten your data

```
data = [
 {date:"2011",type: "line0", amount:20}
 ...
]
```

Then nest your data by type

```
nested = d3.nest()
 .key( (d) -> return d.type )
 .entries(data)
```

Then append your line groups

```
# Line Groups
groups = container.selectAll('g.full-line')
  .data(nested, (d) -> return d.key )

# ENTER
groups.enter().append('svg:g')
.attr( 'class', (d,i) -> "full-line#{i}" )

# EXIT
d3.transition(groups.exit()).remove()

# TRANSITION
d3.transition(groups)
```

Then append your chart lines

```
# Individual Lines
lines = groups.selectAll('.line').data (d)-> [d.values]

# ENTER
lines.enter().append("svg:path")
 .attr("class","line")
 .attr("d", d3.svg.line()
  .interpolate(interpolate)
  .defined(defined)
  .x( (d,i) -> return xScale(d,i) )
  .y( (d,i) -> return yScale(d,i) ) )

# EXIT
d3.transition( groups.exit().selectAll('.line') )
  .attr("d", 
    d3.svg.line()
      .interpolate(interpolate)
      .defined(defined)
      .x( (d,i) -> return xScale(d,i) )
      .y( (d,i) -> return yScale(d,i) ) )

# TRANSITION
d3.transition(lines)
  .attr("d", 
 d3.svg.line()
   .interpolate(interpolate)
   .defined(defined)
       .x( (d,i) -> return xScale(d,i) )
       .y( (d,i) -> return yScale(d,i) ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks

I ended up using something similar.

```
/* Transform Data */
data = data.map(function (d) {
    return {
      country: d.country,
         date: new Date(d.year.toString()),
         value: d.value
     };
});

/* Nest Data */
data = d3.nest().key(function (d) {
    return d.country;
}).entries(data);`
```